# C# WPF Button Style Template Not Showing Background Image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

I am putting together a very simple WPF Window to demonstrate how the style the end user has asked for looks. As there are a number of repeated button type objects I wanted to make them have a style in the window that can then be transferred to the real application once adjustments have been made.

The problem I face is that the user wishes to have images for their buttons, when I set the background image within the button itself then it shows perfectly and behaves as I want (change of image on mouseover etc). When I move that formatting into the Style everything till works but the background images don't show. I am sure I am missing something very simple but I cannot see it.

The code I have generated is below :-

```
<Window x:Class="SkinningDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SkinnigDemo"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="DemoWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MainButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/Button1.png" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Name="border" 
                            BorderThickness="0">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                                <Setter Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/Button1.png"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF266C38"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/Button2.png"/>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#220A88"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="Home">
        <Grid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF220A88" Opacity="0.15"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="68" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="737" Source="images/Master Logo transparent.png"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="62" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="750" Margin="36,96,0,0" Foreground="#FF266C38" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"><Run Language="en-gb" Text="Sample Welcome Text will be placed here once agreed..."/></TextBlock>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="111" Margin="36,0,0,0" Stroke="#220A88" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="348" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF266C38" Opacity="0.25"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="111" Margin="427,0,0,0" Stroke="#220A88" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="348" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF266C38" Opacity="0.25"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="111" Margin="36,295,0,0" Stroke="#220A88" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="348" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF266C38" Opacity="0.25"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="111" Margin="427,295,0,0" Stroke="#220A88" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="348" RadiusX="10" RadiusY="10">
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF266C38" Opacity="0.25"/>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="56" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="311" Margin="54,163,0,0" Foreground="#FF220A88"><Run Language="en-gb" Text="First functional text will go here..."/></TextBlock>
        <Button x:Name="Button1" Style="{StaticResource MainButtonStyle}" Content="View Function 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="82,205,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="258" FontSize="18">
        </Button>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="56" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="311" Margin="446,163,0,0" Foreground="#FF220A88"><Run Language="en-gb" Text="Second Functional Text will go here..."/></TextBlock>
        <Button x:Name="Button2" Style="{StaticResource MainButtonStyle}" Content="View Function 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="472,205,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="258" FontSize="18"/>

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="56" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="311" Margin="56,294,0,0" Foreground="#FF220A88"><Run Language="en-gb" Text="Third Functional Text will go here"/></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="56" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="311" Margin="446,295,0,0" Foreground="#FF220A88"><Run Language="en-gb" Text="Fourth functional text will go here..."/></TextBlock>
        <Button x:Name="Button3" Style="{StaticResource MainButtonStyle}" Content="View Function 3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="472,343,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="258" FontSize="18"/>

        <Button x:Name="Button4" Style="{StaticResource MainButtonStyle}" Content="View Function 4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="80,343,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="258" FontSize="18"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As I say the background images do not display on the screen, but if I remove the style and set it all locally with exactly the same values it works perfectly :-

```
<Button x:Name="Button1"  Content="View Function 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="82,205,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="258" FontSize="18">
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/Button1.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
```

Thanks in anticipation of the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing around with your nicely looking XAML I noticed that you need to say "bind" the Background brush to the root element of your control template which is a border, to get background images displayed.

If you just insert `Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"` under the line `<Border Name="border"` it'll basically work out fine., like:

```
  <Border Name="border"
           Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
           BorderThickness="0">
```

Comment: I believe he also needs to specify his target on the Setters, otherwise it won't know whose Background to change.  Example: `Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border"...`.  Also also, he needs to remove that first occurrence of Setter on the Background that he wrote right before the Setter on the Template, or else it will override any mouse over events and always keep the Background as Button1.png.

Comment: Thanks to you both. The first answer caused the image of the button to appear and I also needed to remove the first occurrence of the setter background to make the mouse over events work. All working great now